# unir resultados en mysql

Tags: mysql

hola ojala me puedan ayudar 
 la verdad es que no se como podre unir los resultados

```
SELECT 
    p.SKU,
    p.pt_part,
    p.pt_color,
    p.pt_talla,
    p.pt_draw,
    p.pt_promo,
    p.pt_desc1,
    p.pt_rev,
    o.pod_part,
    o.po_nbr,
    o.vd_sort,
    o.po_vend,
    o.po_ord_date,
    o.pod_contract,
    o.pod_qty_ord,
    o.pod_qty_rcvd

FROM 
    productos as p
JOIN 
    ordenes as o
ON 
    p.SKU = o.pod_part 
WHERE
    p.SKU like '11111111110338' 
    and p.pt_promo like 'INV2017'
```

la idea es que yo pueda buscar por código, color y la talla por separados 
y pueda buscar por algo asi

`p.pt_part like '111111111' and p.pt_color like '103' and p.pt_talla like '38'` y esto salga completo 11111111110338 para asi poder coincidir los valores con la otra tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Al final era asi ( SELECT p.SKU,
                            p.pt_part, 
                            p.pt_color,
                            p.pt_talla, 
                            p.pt_draw, 
                            p.pt_promo, 
                            p.pt_desc1, 
                            p.pt_rev, 
                            o.pod_part,
                            o.po_nbr,
                            o.vd_sort, 
                            o.po_vend,
                            o.po_ord_date,
                            o.pod_contract,
                            o.pod_qty_ord,
                            o.pod_qty_rcvd
                            FROM productos as p
                            LEFT JOIN ordenes as o
                            ON p.SKU = o.pod_part
                            WHERE p.pt_part = '111111111' and p.pt_color = '105' and p.pt_talla = '38' and pt_promo = 'inv2017'")`

Comment: Y como haría en el caso de querer mostrar resultados de 2 tablas, por ejemplo tengo "ingresos y egresos", ambas tablas tienen los mismos campos, con los mismos nombres y orden, comparten un campo llamado tabla la cual es "I o E" segun Ingresos y Egresos, necesito listar los resultados de ambas tablas pero que se muestre el campo tabla segun corresponda, intenté con UNION pero lo que hace es unirlos laterales, necesito que los resultados se unan por filas y no por columnas.

Comment: @Arcaela haz una pregunta distinta. Si usas los comentarios para hacer una pregunta relacionada nadie los verá

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función CONCAT para concatenar campos de la salida:

```
SELECT 
    p.SKU,
    CONCAT(p.pt_part, p.pt_color, p.pt_talla) concatenacion,
    p.pt_part,
    p.pt_color,
    p.pt_talla,
    p.pt_draw,
    p.pt_promo,
    p.pt_desc1,
    p.pt_rev,
    o.pod_part,
    o.po_nbr,
    o.vd_sort,
    o.po_vend,
    o.po_ord_date,
    o.pod_contract,
    o.pod_qty_ord,
    o.pod_qty_rcvd

FROM 
    productos as p
JOIN 
    ordenes as o
ON 
    p.SKU = o.pod_part 
WHERE
    p.SKU like '11111111110338' 
    and p.pt_promo like 'INV2017'
```